# Two div's with parent pushing each other down

Tags: css, width

I'm trying to fit to divs inside parent without space and using one with defined pixels and the other one with a percentage. Without pushing the other down. Currently I have

```
<style>
    .wrapper {overflow: auto;}
    .container {float: left;margin-right: 150px;}
    .menu {float: right;width: 100px;}
    * {margin: 7px; padding:1px;}
</style>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help?

Comment: First things first, `paddin` should be `padding` and your "wrapper" div does not have a closing `>`

Comment: Your question **"...pushing each other down"** comment **"Without pushing the other down..."** So which one is real? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try using these styles:

```
.wrapper {padding-right:150px;}
.container {float: left; width:100%;}
.menu {float: right;width: 100px; margin-right:-150px;}
```

Please note your menu class has a capital M in your example but your stylesheet uses a small m

An example can be seen here http://jsfiddle.net/ACk9B/